# What would be life living in an underground magma bubble city?

Tags: technology, earth, population

Let's say, we've surpassed all tolerances of population. But, mega-corporations found a creative way to solve the problem. They dug into the Earth to build bubble cities in magma. They have access to (transparent) unobtainium which can withstand and block extremely high temperature and pressure. Energy shouldn't be a problem. And, even agriculture can be possible in an controlled environment. What would be life living in such city? What can be challenges?

Some examples:

- Parents displaying kids new structures in the 100% yellow/red sky and sharing how night sky look like on the surface.
- Warnings to everyone: There's a city hull integrity issue. Everyone wear their unobtainium suits in case we need to abandon the city. Ours bots are out for a look.
- Vacation for surface tourism. Poors can't get to see surface in their lifetime.

Comment: What was the incentive for digging into the crust/mantle rather than building a station in space? There's a reason we've been to space and haven't been very far underground.

Comment: @Frostfyre Space is a dangerous place. There are energy issues, too. Let's say that Sun went chaotic in my case..

Comment: An earthquake is going to wreak havoc on your underground city in much the same way a solar storm would on a space station. There's also significantly more solar energy available in space than on the surface. If the Sun goes chaotic, you won't have a population problem anymore.

Comment: @Frostfyre It's bubble, remember? A strong bubble which can't be popped.. It can just float to another place. BTW, you are turning down my framework. There can be several reasons for not choosing space. It may just not be feasible or financial or political.

Comment: @Frostfyre Let's say, Space is already claimed by a mega-corporation which won't allow space colonies.

Comment: Not attempting to rip apart your idea, just trying to point out flaws in your decision that would pull me out of the story. Also, declaring a monopoly on LEO (I'll assume you didn't mean _all_ space) seems like an equally hard sell, given the current space-neutrality construct.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few challenges to be had here in maintaining the system...mostly to do with the fact that you have created a bubble ecosystem and have to recycle everything.

**Recycle Everything**

Oxygen production and CO2 Scrubbing would be a must. You'd have to do this artificially. Trying to do it with plants simply wouldn't work in a contained environment. A single human requires about 50 liters of Oxygen per hour. A single leaf of a plant produces about 5 milliliters of Oxygen per hour. So, you'd need about 10,000 leaves per person. So, any issue with the atmospheric system would be a problem.

On top of that (and coupled with my next point) every ecosystem has finite resources...yours are just massively more limited because you are in a closed system. You would have to recycle everything, chemically breakdown toxins into useful materials, and so on.

In short, any waste recycling issue that may be present in a generation ship must also be managed by your bubble city.

**Drift**

As you mentioned in a comment, the bubbles can float around in the mantle. This means that they could easily drift away from any access point back to the surface, and be cut off entirely from the rest of the world. You could end up isolated entirely.

**Sinking too deep = wonky gravity**

Gravity is centered on the core of the planet, but it is uniformly generated by all mass that make it up. As you sank deeper into the mantle, you'd start having all the mass above you pulling up, opposing the force pulling you down. While you'd never get zero-g effects, you would have varying strengths of net, downward gravity, depending on how deep you were.

**Mantle Turbulence**

Our planet's mantle (as far as we can tell) is not a nice place to be. There is a lot of turbulence and flow down there (enough to move tectonic plates around) and your city may have some very bumpy days. For example, if you hit a magmatic uplift (the theorized cause of a volcanic hotspot), you could find your city being propelled upwards into the crust.

**Apocalypse for the surface dwellers?**

This is quite a bit of a stretch, more added for fun than because it would have a serious possibility of happening...but it is theoretically possible that if your bubble wandered into a magmatic uplift, you could get tossed up against the crust, and potentially (depending on how big you are) get nudged up into a magma chamber...say the one beneath Yellowstone. Your city may block some stuff up, causing an increase in pressures in there since you are in the way of the normal ways all that energy gets vented. And that pressure has to go somewhere...so it blows the top off the Yellowstone caldera and causes a global extinction event...also propelling your city into the sky.

Comment: you mean propelling the city into *orbit*!! Now the space corporations have to deal with an unwanted colony, war is imminent! (okay sry... got carried away)

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't just be 'floating' on magma, it is under very high pressures, you'd be forcing an open space inside this, against pressures that cause volcanoes to erupt.  Just 'digging' down to that magma would create a new volcano.

These are forces that move whole continents, shake cities to the ground, space would be much cheaper and easier place to put people.

Comment: Or, you know, the surface of the earth...

Comment: Don't turn down framework of the question. You don't know anything about future tech.

Comment: @SS You started talking about a 'floating' city on lava, like there is a huge chamber with a lake of molten rock, that only exists in Lord of the Rings.  that chamber would be filled up and your city would just be a 'bubble' inside it.